# Are there any C99 standard-based limitations or drawbacks in having very many conditions in an IF statement, and if so, what are they?

Tags: c

I made a `for` loop that just checks, on each iteration, if an index is equal to an integer, and I realized that I can just write a very long if statement and make it much more readable than it is now.

I want to know if there are any explicit rules or undefined behaviours, limitations, or drawbacks in having 100 conditions in an `if` statement connected by:

1. `&&`
2. `||`

according to the C99 standard, compiled on a modern x64 Intel machine with the newest gcc.

Comment: One drawback is possible side-effects not actioned with the short-circuit is applied.

Comment: I propose to provide one [mre] each for the two versions you have in mind.

Comment: @John3136 - pretty sure we shouldn't be making comments and assumptions about someone's code being horrible (*especially* since nothing has been shared in the question).

Comment: Why would it be more efficient all in the same conditional? The underlying code needs the same testing and branching as if you wrote them seperately. The main issue is readability, for example `if(x >= 0 && x < width)` is more readable than given on separate lines, with another code block and more indentation.

Comment: Please edit to include your relevant code and related details (sample data, errors, etc), along with any issue(s) you're running into. Note: opinion-based questions are off-topic, so even with more details, this will likely remain closed as "off-topic".

Comment: @DavidMakogon-Let me reword- if a VERY LONG if statement is the more readable of your two options then you are not writing maintainable code.

Comment: Why are you asking about the old C99 standard (which is 24 years old) instead of the modern C18 standard (which is only 5 years old)? Is this intentional?

Comment: You need to show an example of actual code, at least to give us a feel of what you're trying to do. This feels like XY problem, because 100 conditions in one if-statement sounds unmaintainable, and quite likely something that could be written much more cleanly and with better performance. It's hard to say, because you have not shown any code.

Comment: One limitation that may apply is that [ISO C11 only requires that a compiler support "4095 characters in a logical source line"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1). However, this limit can be easily circumvented by using several [logical source lines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases#Phase_2) for your `if` statement. The actual limits of gcc are probably much higher than the minimum limits imposed by ISO C. Are you asking about the minimum limits of ISO C or the actual limits of gcc?

Comment: @paddy no I don't need to. Anyone after the first class of C 101 should know what an if statement with multiple conditions looks like. I am not looking for a solution for my code. I am looking for an answer to a specific question. If it says in the standard that an if statement can have max 1024 conditions, that's what I want to know. If for each condition, the computer starts to incrementally lag, that's what I want to know. Every other comment trying to "improve" my code or whatever, I don't care about.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I am interested in any limits. The one about characters in a line is pretty interesting and important to know in general, so thanks for that. EDIT: limits of gcc are probably too large to ever encounter, so maybe isoc limits are better to know

Comment: There's no need for hostility. Your original question mentions that you _rewrote_ some code to be in one big if-statement. On the one hand, sure, you're asking about the limitations. But what I was saying is it sounds very fishy to me. There is a good reason why basically no code does what you're describing. Even automatically-generated code. I'm suggesting that there might be a better way to solve your problem. You have decided you need this, but you have shown zero code to convince anyone else that it's necessary.

Comment: @paddy: Re “You need to show an example of actual code”: No, they do not. Questions about theory, general principles, and common behaviors are on-topic for Stack Overflow, and this question can be answered on that basis. There is a specific limit that is relevant, in C 1999 5.2.4.1 1. And there are drawbacks that can be discussed in a useful way.

Comment: @paddy: Re “There's no need for hostility”: Where do you see hostility? The first sentence of the previous question by sneaker denied there was any need to do what you said they need to do. That is true, and is a simple statement of fact, not a hostile statement. The second sentence says anybody with basic knowledge of C should understand the question asked, and that is also true, and it is not a comment aimed at your knowledge. The rest of the comment explains the question in more detail.

Comment: @paddy: Re “I'm suggesting that there might be a better way to solve your problem”: You are not their mommy. You have offered to provide information different from what OP asked. If they want to proceed with the question they asked, that is fine. It is a reasonable question, on topic of Stack Overflow, and can be answered. Re “you have shown zero code to convince anyone else that it's necessary”: That is not your decision to make; you do not speak for other people’s decisions or beliefs.

Comment: @Yunnosch It looks like it is inherently impossible to provide a *minimal* example here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if there are any explicit rules or undefined behaviours, limitations,…

C 1999 5.2.4 1 says “Both the translation and execution environments constrain the implementation of language translators and libraries…” This means that a compiler is not required to be able to compile every theoretically conforming C program of every length. It may fail when given programs that contain too much complexity of various kinds.

5.2.4.1 1 specifies minimum thresholds that a conforming C implementation must be able to support, albeit specified weakly as that an implementation shall be able to translate and execute one program meeting all of the thresholds. None of these thresholds are directly relevant to an `if` with 100 conditions. Two that might affect it are:

> — 63 nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full expression
>
> …
>
> — 4095 characters in a logical source line

You do not mention parentheses in your question, and 4095 characters in a logical source line is easily avoided by dividing the statement into multiple lines.

> … drawbacks in having 100 conditions in an if statement connected by…

The major concern here would not be limitations or drawbacks in the compiler but rather bad design. The minimum quality I would expect for a compiler is that it report if it is unable to correctly compile a program. We should be able to expect that, if the compiler produces a program without reporting an error in compilation, the resulting program will execute correctly.

Further, compilers of good quality may optimize the program and produce good code for the `if` statement, possibly better than what the author has nominally written.

However, in programming in general, opportunities abound for both optimization and expressiveness. An `if` statement with 100 conditions is likely rich with possibilities for alternate designs. We might use tables to record and look up which cases should pass or fail the test instead of hard-coding them into code. Or we might use other data-driven solutions, such as a tree representing the conditions to be tested. We might optimize the tests to try to most frequently distinguish cases first. We might mathematically analyze the conditions to simplify them. We might rewrite the conditions to be clearer to human readers.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know if there are any explicit rules or undefined behaviours, limitations, or drawbacks in having 100 conditions in an if statement [...] according to the C99 standard

No, there are no explicit rules or undefined behaviors.  (There are plenty of limitations and drawbacks, as discussed at length in this question's other answers and comments, but those are stylistic, not anything that a compiler would care about.)

> compiled on a modern x64 Intel machine with the newest gcc

If your question is about the language as defined by the C99 standard, it doesn't matter which compiler you're using.

On the one hand, its not unusual for computer programs (including compilers) to have various limitations, to not be able to operate on completely unbounded inputs.  But on the other hand, it has always been somewhat a part of the C philosophy, and definitely a part of the GNU/FSF philosophy, to avoid any and all arbitrary limitations whenever possible.  So I would be very surprised to hear that gcc had any limitation of the kind you're asking about.

I constructed a "simple" `if` statement of the form

```
if(a1 == b1 && a2 == b2 && a3 == b3 && … && a98 == b98 && a99 == b99 && a100 == b100)
```

I tested it under two versions of gcc (4.6.3 and 10.2.1), with and without `-std=c99`.  I didn't get any errors.  (But I didn't test the generated code to make sure it worked perfectly.)

As Eric Postpischil mentioned in his answer, it would be very surprising if a compiler compiled a complicated expression without error, but generated code which behaved improperly.  That is (thankfully) a rare failure mode in practice.

Answer (score 2):

#### What the C standard says

Both the C99 and C11 standards (C99 [§5.2.4.1 Translation limits](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.2.4.1); C11 [§5.2.4.1 Translation limits](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1)) say:

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:<sup>18)</sup>
>
> - 127 nesting levels of blocks
> - 63 nesting levels of conditional inclusion
> - 12 pointer, array, and function declarators (in any combinations) modifying an arithmetic, structure, union, or void type in a declaration
> - 63 nesting levels of parenthesized declarators within a full declarator
> - 63 nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full expression
> - 63 significant initial characters in an internal identifier or a macro name (each universal character name or extended source character is considered a single character)
> - 31 significant initial characters in an external identifier (each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 0000FFFF or less is considered 6 characters, each universal character name specifying a short identifier of 00010000 or more is considered 10 characters, and each extended source character is considered the same number of characters as the corresponding universal character name, if any)19)
> - 4095 external identifiers in one translation unit
> - 511 identifiers with block scope declared in one block
> - 4095 macro identifiers simultaneously defined in one preprocessing translation unit
> - 127 parameters in one function definition
> - 127 arguments in one function call
> - 127 parameters in one macro definition
> - 127 arguments in one macro invocation
> - 4095 characters in a logical source line
> - 4095 characters in a string literal (after concatenation)
> - 65535 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)
> - 15 nesting levels for #included files
> - 1023 case labels for a switch statement (excluding those for any nested * switch statements)
> - 1023 members in a single structure or union
> - 1023 enumeration constants in a single enumeration
> - 63 levels of nested structure or union definitions in a single struct-declaration-list
>
> 18) Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible.

Footnote 19 points to a 'future direction' about the maximum length of identifiers, stating that anything less than 255 should be regarded as obsolescent.

The same limits apply to C18 (C17) and the latest draft of C23.

None of those limits directly applies to your described scenario, to the extent that your scenario *is* described.  The one most likely to apply is "63 nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full expression".  The 'logical line length' limit is trivially circumventable by adding a newline between pairs of tokens.  Just don't create any identifiers that are longer than the line length limit — but the identifiers would be full-scale essays and hence totally impractical.  This whole answer is only a little over 4 KiB.

So, it is unlikely that the compiler will have any problems with even a quite complex `if` condition.  "Only" 100 terms is unlikely to break it.

However, anybody who understands the code with 100 conditions in a single `if` condition is a miracle worker (or maybe a liar).  I suppose that if the conditions are all systematic:

```
if (strcmp(a, "ABC") == 0 ||
    strcmp(a, "BCD") == 0 ||
    …
   )
```

then it is understandable — it just isn't very good code.  If the conditions are wildly diverse, or if there are nested conditions (admixtures of `||` and `&&` with parentheses and maybe some negation operators thrown in for good measure), then people are not going to understand the code.

#### Don't Do It!

IMNSHO, the motto for you should be "Don't do it!"  There must be better ways of dealing with whatever you're testing.  Alternatives include loops and functions.  The compiler limits should rarely, if ever, be a concern to you.  When they are a concern, there is usually some sort of code structuring problem.  For example, if you have a function that needs 128 arguments and your compiler adheres to the lower bound (127) specified by the standard, you've not structured your data very well — you should probably be using structure types to group some of those arguments together.